# SQL Server could not disable publishing and distribution

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replication

**SQL Server could not disable publishing and distribution on 'server_name'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)**

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Database 'distribution' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
Changed database context to 'master'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Note: Earlier I have deleted **distribution** data files manually, now I need to implement replication mechanism on my production server.

Waiting for best/vital suggestions.

Comment: How did you delete the distribution data files manually?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you delete the **distribution** data files manually?

The distribution database in SQL Server requires special attention and dropping it in this fashion can wreak havoc on your distribution server.  Doing so will cause existing publications to error on synchronization and further attempts to disable publishing and distribution will fail.  This really puts a DBA between a rock and a hard place.

If the distribution database data and log files are still intact you could recreate the distribution database via attach like how I describe here:  http://www.sqlrepl.com/sql-server/accidentally-dropped-distribution-database/

If the distribution database data and log files are **not** intact I'm afraid you're going to have some troubles disabling publishing and distribution on this machine.  Reinstall?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm new to DBA filed and I would like to know internal mechanism of replication setup (in-depth).